# Expanding css box to the correct text height

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a label that expands upon click to show detail text. I found this collapsible card library online and it works fine except for expanding to the right size.

Here is the relevant css:

```
.collapse-card {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #777;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: rgba(241,240,240,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.collapse-card * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.collapse-card.active {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18824);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18824);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18824);
  z-index: 200;
  margin: 1rem -3rem;
}
```

I created this fiddle that shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/6gozpmeb/

When you click on the box it first expands to a height bigger than the text for a second then resizes to the correct height. How can i eliminate this effect?
Setting a fixed height eliminates the problem, but the size of the text is dynamic so I can't predict the height.

Edit: I want to keep the horizontal expanding effect, so removing `margin: 1rem -3rem;` from .collapse-card.active eliminates the desired animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked to maintain the same animation effect, without having the expanding longer than the text height, is to give .collapse-card.active a fixed width.
Not optimal either but much better than the height flickering problem. 
If anybody has a better answer that maintains the same animation, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .collapse-card.active {width: 130%;transition: .4s;margin-left: 0; }
 .collapse-card {width: 100%;margin-left: 15%;}
 /* add Above css */
```

check this link
https://jsfiddle.net/2fu7r6yc/

Comment: The problem is removing this margin affects the width of the expanded box.

Comment: remove the margin there and move it into the .collapse-card

Comment: .collapse-card {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #777;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s
  background-color: rgba(241,240,240,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 1rem -3rem
}

Comment: @BrOsCoRe moving the margin to .collapse-card gives it the expanded effect, instead of assigning it to the .collapse-card active. It removes the expanding animation which is supposed to be there.

Comment: @blackCode for me it doesnt removes the animation? at least not in the fiddle.

Comment: It removes the horizontal (width) animation on click, which is unfortunately part of the desired animation.

Comment: if you compare your fiddle to the original fiddle, you can see that the label (collapsed) expands horizontally on click.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrOsCoRe/Le8xgj71/1/)

remove the margin as @Harsh Bala said and add it here:

**CSS**

```
.collapse-card {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #777;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s
  background-color: rgba(241,240,240,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 1rem -3rem
}
```

Comment: moving the margin to .collapse-card gives it the expanded effect, instead of assigning it to the .collapse-card active. It removes the expanding animation which is supposed to be there.